# How to change the site setting of unsecured(http) websites on chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, ssl, clipboard

I need to make the site setting of **clipboard** to **allow** but it's coming **block** and blurred(not changeable).

for the unsecured websites(HTTP).

So, Is there any way to edit this setting and change it to allow?

[image: site setting page of unsecured site]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, there isn't any way to do this. Per the [Clipboard specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#navigator-interface), the clipboard can only be accessed by secure contexts (HTTPS) (see `SecureContext` in the specification). Therefore, all browsers should only allow this API for HTTPS.

The chrome browser is open source, so this secure context requirement can also be verified [here in the source code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/modules/clipboard/clipboard.idl;l=8;drc=918877f7415f70fb5c1ae1b62541ff34a3d02c1a).

Comment: I would also like to add that it can also be used on localhost.

Answer (score 10):

One option here is to add the origin for the website in question to the Chrome
#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure flag. This will then allow clipboard access on the origin. Of course, this is only advisable if you really do trust the insecure origin.

[image]

Comment: still works today. would have liked a wildcard so i could whitelist a range of ports from a LAN address